# how do I avoid the Ambiguous Column error in SQL?

Tags: sql

From the code below, I am trying to merge 3 tables together. In one of these tables, it contains the year at which each project is completed and its project number. I am trying to join the tables but only contain the most up to date version of each project. Currently I am having the issue of the column "JobNO" being ambiguous and also there is an error with "YearMonth" which is the column that contains the dates. What is the best solution for this problem?

```
SELECT  LoadId.JobNo, LoadId.YearMonth, LoadId.Phase, JobCost.Depth, 
    JobCost.UOM, JobCost.CostCode, JobCost.CostCodeDesc, CostCat.Category, 
    CostCat.CurrentBudget,




FROM  CostCat INNER JOIN
      JobCost ON CostCat.JobCostID = JobCost.ID INNER JOIN  
      LoadId ON JobCost.LoadIdID = LoadId.ID INNER JOIN
      (SELECT JobNo, MAX(YearMonth) As MaxDate  FROM LoadId GROUP BY JobNo)
      LoadId2 ON LoadId.JobNo = LoadId2.JobNo AND LoadId.YearMonth = LoadId2.MaxDate  


GROUP BY JobNo, YearMonth, Phase, Depth, UOM, JobCost.CostCode, CostCodeDesc, Category, CostCat.CurrentBudget
```

Comment: Qualify the column names in the group by clause with the table's name just like your select statement.

Comment: And qualifying all references gets simpler if you use short but meaningful table aliases for all of your tables.

Answer (score 1):

> how do I avoid the Ambiguous Column error in SQL?

The answer is simple.  You qualify *all* column references in the query.  That includes the `GROUP BY` clause and subqueries.

Comment: Im new to SQL. I have qualified all of them but now I am getting a Select error. What would it look like?

Comment: @Apmartin . . . Ask a new question with the query you are using and the text of the error.